# jQuery Autocomplete on TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, tinymce

I almost got jQuery Autocomplete to work perfectly with TinyMCE. I got everything working, except for the keyboard response. More precisely, what I can't get is to enable the user to press the down arrow key and move through the options using the keyboard.

I tried handling the down key press, and focusing the autocomplete element, or the first child, but no luck.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Some simplified code example:

```
ed.onKeyUp.add(function (ed, e) {
    if (e.keyIdentifier == "Down")
        txt.autocomplete("widget").focus();
}
```

Where *ed* is the TinyMCE editor, txt is the *textarea* jQuery's Autocomplete is activated.

Thanks.

Comment: we need some code here. what have you tried?